# Cannot parse mutiple json rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitterapi to get the friends list in php and I have encoded the result as a json array, but I cannot parse the json array in javascript.I have validated the json array produced by the php and its a valid json array. Below is my code.

### php

```
$friends = array();
$friend_list = array();
$myfriend = array();
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($CONSUMER_KEY, $CONSUMER_SECRET,oauth_token,oauth_token_secret);
 $friends =$connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false&count=200);

foreach($friends as $friend) {
           if(!empty($friend))
           {
           foreach($friend as $value)
           {
                $friend_list['id']=$value->id; 
                $friend_list['screen_name']= $value->screen_name;
                $friend_list['name']= $value->name;
                $friend_list['profile_image_url']= $value->profile_image_url;
                $friend_list['location']= $value->location;
                array_push($myfriend, $friend_list);

            }

           }
       } 

  $newarray = json_encode($myfriend);
```

'

### javascript

```
<script>
var obj1 = JSON.parse('<?php echo $newarray ;?>');

console.log(obj1); // am not getting anything in console
</script>
```

### EDITED

output from `echo $newarray;`

```
[
    {
        "id": 50393960,
        "screen_name": "BillGates",
        "name": "Bill Gates",
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1884069342/BGtwitter_normal.JPG",
        "location": "Seattle, WA"
    },
    {
        "id": 141527741,
        "screen_name": "prakashraaj",
        "name": "Prakash Raj",
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2951815972/ab32fb806b480d0dc761805ae4ef9775_normal.jpeg",
        "location": "india"
    },
    {
        "id": 88856792,
        "screen_name": "aamir_khan",
        "name": "Aamir Khan",
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2254031972/_MG_2190_normal.jpeg",
        "location": "Mumbai"
    },
    {
        "id": 107318424,
        "screen_name": "bipsluvurself",
        "name": "Bipasha Basu",
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/419745345178832896/8JvqwEM9_normal.jpeg",
        "location": "Mumbai, India"
    }
]
```

Please help, am stuck with this

Comment: You are missing a `"` at the end of the string literal where the URL is contained. But that might just be a typo here. If you are directly echoing the JSON into the JavaScript source code, then you can just do: `var obj1 = <?php echo $newarray ;?>;`, and let JS interpret it as object literal.

Comment: try it without the single quotes in JSON.parse

Comment: @asifrc: That would be wrong. `JSON.parse` expects a string and you would pass an object.

Comment: There is the possibility that your JSON contains a `'`, in which case you would produce invalid JavaScript because the string literal would end prematurely. By ommitting the whole `JSON.parse` thing, you are avoiding this problem.

Comment: @FelixKling I am having this problem only if I am getting multiple rows. For one row it is working eg: echo json_encode($friend_list)

Comment: How does `$myfriend` and `$newarray` look like when there are multiple rows? Do a `print_r($myfriend)` and `print_r($newarray)` and see what their value is. What did you do to debug the problem? Does the console show any error? What does the **generated** code look like? There is not enough information contained in your question to really help you.

Comment: @FelixKling i have updated the question with the output I get,please have a look

Comment: That looks fine to me. `var data = <?php echo $newarray; ?>; console.log(data);` should definitely work. That's of course assuming that those lines are also in the same file where you create `$newarray`.

Comment: @FelixKling yes it is. but its not working , If suppose am having only  one row eg: if i echo   $friend_list its fine. i get the array in console

Comment: Well, without more information there really is nothing we can do. The generated JSON looks good, I showed you how you could integrate it into JavaScript. With the information you provided, it *has* to work. *"but it's not working"* isn't really a helpful error description. As I already said, have a look at the **generated** JavaScript code and see if there are any oddities there.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly output the json:

Change to:

```
var obj1 = <?php echo $newarray ;?>;
```

For example:

```
<?php
$newarray = json_encode(array('name' => 'srain'));
?>
var obj1 = <?php echo $newarray ;?>;
```

It will output:

```
  var obj1 = {"name":"srain"};
```

***update***

If your js script is not in the same file with the php code, the `$newarray` will be null.

Comment: Thanks, I am not doing i tmanually, I am getting the array from the twitter api, I get the array in php, I encode it , but I cannot parse the array in javascript

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of information about how you validated json array, this is what I can recommend. Change your javascript to:

```
<script>
var jsonString = '<?php echo $newarray ;?>';
console.log(jsonString);
var obj1 = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(obj1); // am not getting anything in console
</script>
```

You can see the content of `jsonString` in the javascript console. That should give you hints about what is going wrong.

Note:You are fetching JSON content from twitter, converting it to PHP data structure and converting it back to JSON. Sending the JSON string from twitter to javascript is far more efficient - if there is no need to filter/alter the twitter returned data.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not displaying anything

Comment: I validated the output of php . I can get the response from the api, but I cannot parse it in javascript

Comment: You have a problem of sending the JSON to javascript if `console.log(jsonString);` does not print anything.